# Получить значение кодировки страницы из тега <meta>

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Имеется строка, которая содержит в себе мета-тег кодировки страницы, это может быть UTF-8, Windows-1251, KOI8-R и другие.

meta-тег в зависимости от ситуации имеет разный вид, в нем не всегда может присутствовать явное указание кодировки.

В данной ситуации meta-тег выглядит следующим образом:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=koi8-r">
```

Каким способом можно через PHP вытащить значение charset в мета-теге, если оно присутствует? Мне необходимо получить только содержимое тега charset, в данной ситуации я хочу получить строку с содержанием "koi8-r".

P.S - хочу уточнить, что решение через DOM PHP мне не подходит, желательно использовать регулярное выражение.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Может такой вариант? Протестировал на `UTF-8, Windows-1251, KOI8-R`

```
$str = '<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">';
preg_match('/charset=(.*)"/', $str, $matches);
print_r($matches[1]);
```

Если нужно еще учитывать такой вариант `<meta charset="utf-8">`

```
$str = '<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=koi8-r">';
$str2 = '<meta charset="Utf-8">';
if (preg_match('/charset="*(.*)"/', $str2, $matches)) {
print_r($matches[1]);
} else {
print_r("кодировка не установлена");}
```

**P.S:** Если еще пробелы и одинарные кавычки нужно учесть:

```
$str = '<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf - 8">';
$str2 = "<meta charset='Utf-8'>";
$result = preg_replace("/\s+/", "", $str); //удаляем пробелы в строке
if (preg_match('/charset=[\'"]*(.+)[\'"]+/', $result, $matches)) {
print_r($matches[1]);
}
else {
print_r("кодировка не установлена");}
```

Comment: Здравствуйте. Я плохо разбираюсь в регулярных выражениях, из-за чего не смог реализовать данный функционал самостоятельно. Ваш вариант подходит просто идеально, большое спасибо.

Comment: @Fox добрый вечер, рад что помог ))

Comment: `charset` может не только в meta использоваться. // сс @Fox

Comment: Например, http://htmlbook.ru/html/link.

Comment: @Qwertiy да, если будет в таком виде `<meta charset="utf-8">` . Сейчас немного подправлю, спасибо

Comment: @Qwertiy да, вы правы, но я работаю с почтой и получаю meta и head заголовка text\http отправленного письма, в котором в любом случаи работает данный пример :)

Comment: Если учитывать разные варианты, не стоит ли удалить из строки пробелы перед поиском? Вариантов-то масса `charset="utf-8"`, `charset = "utf-8"` и т.д., плюс ещё одинарные/двойные кавычки. Если речь о верстке входящих e-mail -- ни на какой стандарт рассчитывать не приходится.

Comment: @another_login спасибо, дополнил ответ